# Sharepoint site/subsite get zero in size only

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-foundation, site-collection, sub-site, size

Using the script:

```
Get-SPSite | select url, @{label="Size in MB";Expression={$_.usage.storage/1MB}} | Sort-Object -Descending -Property "Size in MB" | Format-Table –AutoSize
```

I always get zero size on sites/subsites collections. What I need actually is to get size on every site/subsite on our internal intranet site. Any other scripts that I have found shows nothing or the same zero size on all sites.
For intranet used Sharepoint Foundation 2010.

Thanks in advance for your time and support.

Comment: What is the output of `Get-SPSite | % {Write-Host $_.Url $_.Usage.Storage}` ?

Comment: Hi @AzizKabyshev, the output what I get is only address of the site without any size mentioned:[link](http://intranet).

Comment: Ok, thanks. Is the account you run powershell under included in Farm Admins group in CA? Also - what does `Get-SPSiteAdministration | ft url,diskused` show?

Comment: Right Aziz, my account is included in Farm Admins in CA, and using the script mentioned above also get only the site address and on DiskUsed, which it is supposed to show something, it shows nothing...

Comment: Can you try with `Start-SPAssignment -Global` added before and `Stop-SPAssignment -Global` after that line?

Comment: Sorry, the same result.

Comment: Can you open "Application management" --> "Site Collection Quotas and Locks" page in CA under the that account, select your site collection and see if "Current storage used" displays any real data?

Comment: Hi Aziz, from CA page, I get size of any site. Actually the issue was on my rights, even I am on Farm Admin, I didn't have required rights. Have tried with another account which got all required info.  Used script was:

Comment: $allsites = Get-SPSite -WebApplication http://intranet -Limit All
$allsites | % {$_ | select @{n='URL';e={$_.url}}, @{n='use';e={$_.usage.storage / 1MB -as [int] }}}

Comment: I'm happy to hear you have sorted it out. Yeah, I was narrowing to `Add-SPShellAdmin`, but weekend broke our dialog :)